# Find full url for query

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a website that I need to access with `requests`
[URL](https://live.euronext.com/en/markets/amsterdam/equities/list).

However, I need to apply a filter. On the website interface, you can find: `SHOW FILTERS --> MARKET --> EURONEXT AMSTERDAM`. How can I apply a filter with python?

Here is code snippet:

```
import requests

data = {
   # there should be a data for post request to filter MARKET --> EURONEXT AMSTERDAM
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://live.euronext.com/en/markets/amsterdam/equities/list",
    data=data,
)
```

How to accesses filtered data with python?

Comment: I looked at the request generated while using the MARKET filter: https://live.euronext.com/en/pd_es/filter/stocks?mics=XAMS%2CTNLA&market=06&initialLetter=&ajax=true. The query parameter is `market=06`. Unfortunately, the value appears to be an ID rather than a human-readable name. Regardless, this isn't a sustainable way to form URLs for filtered results. You need to see if the site publishes an API you can use, or get creative with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) so you can interact with the page via Python.

Comment: Here's the [API information](https://www.euronext.com/en/data/web-services)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot interact with elements on the page using `requests`. This library can only make a request and recieve a response. It isn't a browser that renders the HTML in an interactive window.

You have two options here:

1. Figure out what happens when you click the button. If this causes a HTTP request, then you can recreate that request directly.
2. Use another library such as `playwright` or `selenium` which loads the HTML into a browser. These libraries provide functions which allow you to interact with the page in the same way you will as a user.

The first option is almost always ideal. Using an API to get the data directly is often much less complicated than trying to scrape data from a webpage.

To understand this better, I recommend that you read about the response/request model for HTTP.